# Mysql 8 - Count(*) - performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, mysql-8.0

I have this table with 2 million records

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BODY` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `CREATION_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_USER` (`ID_USER`),
  KEY `CREATION_DATE` (`CREATION_DATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2198623 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The first run of this select returns '1131' in 70 seconds

```
select count(*) from my_table where ID_USER=123 and CREATION_DATE>=2019-07-29
```

The second run returns '1131' in 60 milliseconds.

What do you recommend to improve performance?

More info:

- ID as cardinality 2198623
- ID_USER as cardinality 12788
- CREATION_DATE as cardinality 11909

Comment: create index on (ID_USER, CREATION_DATE)

Comment: Please tell us the real name of `my_table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Duct Tape" option: Remove the index on `ID_User` and replace it with an index on `(ID_User,CREATION_DATE)`.

Best option: Get rid of the `Id` and find another suitable primary key such as `(ID_User,<timestamp>)`.  This is preferable as it would: ensure uniqueness, remove the need for one index, and get rid of a useless column.

Comment: It is rarely wise to use a timestamp in a unique (or `PRIMARY`) key -- what if two things happened in the same second?

Comment: In the unlikely event two things happen in the same *nanosecond* for the same *user* I would want to resolve that conflict.  I'm not sure where you get "rarely wise" because it's pretty common in industries where you have to store/reference multiple versions of the same information.  I'm not sure how you'd enforce a contract if you had any question to which row was in effect as of a given time.

Comment: If `ID_User` is unique (eg, on a `Users` table), then use `PRIMARY KEY(ID_User)`.  If, say, it is a `Orders` table, then have `OrderNumber` being `AUTO_INCREMENT` and use a `PRIMARY KEY(OrderNumber), INDEX(ID_User)` or `PRIMARY KEY(ID_User, OrderNumber), INDEX(OrderNumber)`

Comment: Is that in context of the question, my comment, or neither?  Maybe chat is a better venue https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/111224/database-design-opinions?tab=general